# Sqlite between operator issue

Tags: sqlite, between

I need query to get data between two days.I tried with this.But it gives all records of the table.Between operator is not working.

```
Select * From Test
Where strftime('%d-%m-%Y',Date) Between '01-06-2012' And '30-06-2012'
```

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try on this,

```
Select * From Test
Where strftime('%Y%m%d',Date) Between '20120601' And '20120630'
```